# Authenticated user available in Illuminate\Http\Request but not FormRequest

Tags: php, laravel-8

We want to start using custom requests generated with `php artisan make:request` for authorization and/or validation.

My custom request class extends Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest, as described in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

The same documentation also suggests to perform checks on the user by accessing `$this->user()`. However `$this->user()`, `Auth::user()` and `auth()->user()` all are `null` inside the `authorize` method, while `Auth::check()` returns `false`.

```
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        dd("custom request", $this->user(), Auth::user(), auth()->user(), Auth::check());
        return Auth::user() || Auth::user()->role_id === 2;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, if I change my controller back to using \Illuminate\Http\Request, then both `Auth::user()` and `$this->request->user()` hold the authenticated user (inside the controller's __invoke method). So it's not a general problem with the authentication middleware not working correctly, I suppose. My guess is that dependency injection for the FormRequest doesn't work.

But I'm fairly new to Laravel and I've only recently taken over this project. I've tried to debug it, also together with a colleague, read dozens of threads, asked chatGPT.. Any hints would be highly appreciated!

**Route** looks like this in principle:

```
Route::prefix('contract')->middleware(['web', 'auth'])->group(function () {
    ...
    Route::post('someRoute/{someId}', SomeController::class);
});
```

Comment: Can you show your routes for both cases?

Comment: @Pippo Both cases? Should the routes be configured differently when using a custom request? I thought all I have to do is change the type hint in the Controller for the request. So I only have one case, which I added above.